# Android signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) libwebviewchromium.so

Tags: java, android, android-webview, native

I get "Native crash at /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so" errors many times for android 4.4
Following are the devices include:-

Xperia Z1 (SO-01F)  16  30.2%
Galaxy Tab4 7.0 (degaswifi) 6   11.3%
Galaxy S4 (ja3g)    4   7.5%
Galaxy S3 Neo (s3ve3g)  3   5.7%
Galaxy Note4 (trltetmo) 2   3.8%
Galaxy J1 Ace (j1pop3g) 2   3.8%
荣耀畅玩4C (hwCHM-H)    2   3.8%
Droid Ultra (obake) 2   3.8%
A3-A30 (omega)  2   3.8%
P7 (hwp7)   2   3.8%
Galaxy S4 (jfvelte) 1   1.9%
Galaxy J1 Ace (j1acelte)    1   1.9%
Mate 7 (hwmt7)  1   1.9%
Galaxy J1 (j13g)    1   1.9%
Galaxy S5 (klteatt) 1   1.9%
Galaxy Note2 (t0lteatt) 1   1.9%
RAZR M (smq)    1   1.9%
Galaxy E7 (e7ltehktw)   1   1.9%
Galaxy Tab3 7.0 (lt02ltespr)    1   1.9%
LG Optimus G Pro (geefhd4g) 1   1.9%
Others  2   3.8%

```
    backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000192210  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #01  pc 000000000002038c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #02  pc 0000000000050eab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #03  pc 0000000000029820  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0000000000030b28  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #05  pc 000000000002e1c0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #06  pc 00000000000634d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #07  pc 000000000004fbfd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #08  pc 00000000001923d9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #09  pc 0000000000192f07  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #10  pc 0000000000187fd3  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #11  pc 0000000000189375  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #12  pc 0000000000189e4f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #13  pc 00000000003141ff  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #14  pc 0000000000314883  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #15  pc 0000000000da28f9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #16  pc 0000000000d1a5d1  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #17  pc 0000000000d1a73f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #18  pc 0000000000d1bd47  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #19  pc 0000000000d1bd5d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #20  pc 0000000000d1bd6d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #21  pc 0000000000d5c07b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #22  pc 0000000000d50cf3  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #23  pc 0000000000d50179  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #24  pc 0000000000d28991  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #25  pc 0000000000d26b99  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #26  pc 0000000000d3426d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #27  pc 0000000000d51b85  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #28  pc 0000000000d520b5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #29  pc 0000000000d4d8f3  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #30  pc 0000000000d4d64b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  #31  pc 00000000001b1641  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: if you are using admob, then the problem likely is from there. although they don't know what's going on either. see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/Q-edauZ27g8/e_7wKbcJCgAJ