# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) base.apk

Tags: android, android-ndk

Anyone know how to fix this problem at android?

I received a **report from Google Play**, but I can't find out whats going on with this log chat.

---

pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.fly175.flightbattle <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000032fba2  /data/app/com.android.chrome-sT437I3yEyu2LzrxnSDmBA==/base.apk

Comment: You need to post the rest of the crash.  You're missing most of the trace and all the important information about the error, like the type, address, etc.  All I can tell you from what you posted is that C code derferenced an invalid memory address.

Comment: Hi, this all what i get from Google Play, no more any detail about that.

Comment: The same issue. Have you found something?

Comment: I received report #00  pc 0000000000f0a358  /data/app/com.android.chrome-u21wAEs9HjAX2ZUxwi3mIg==/oat/arm/base.odex

Answer (score 4):

This may be related to banner ads. Other users have reported similar errors (I've seen them too occasionally) where there are Signal 11 crashes in chrome `base.apk` or `libwebviewchromium`.

Similar issues have been reported on SO without resolution ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319314/android-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-libwebviewchromium-so), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694498/my-app-crashes-in-play-console-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr)).

It's been reported to Google [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/nr-su6oQCzw), and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/I6giN0VbVa0). The latest update from the second Google ticket on the issue is recent (June 1, 2018) so it's probably not resolved yet. The second support ticket suggests it may be an issue with Samsung devices in particular.

Unfortunately if it is coming through the banner ad there's probably not much you can do at this point. It's possible you could intercept the error by adding a listener or extending the AdView class, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 3):

The information provided is not enough to give you exact answer But I can tell you the root cause. It is happening due to corrupted memory address in NDK library of this application `com.fly175.flightbattle`.

I am not sure if this is your app or user have installed `flightbattle` and your app also but the reason for crash is `com.fly175.flightbattle`.

**Workaround**:

As Google Play crashes are random crash and difficult to reproduce. You might have the device information as well. Try to create emulator with same spec as the device OR have the same device (that would be better) and use your app (maybe you can run monkey tests) and see if the issue is reproducible. If yes then you will have detailed stacktraces to find the exact issue.

Hope this will be helpful!